# My MacBook Wake up for No Reason

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, sleep-wake, logs

My current system is MacOS Monterey 12.2.1.
I found my MacBook waked up for no reason at night.

At first I though it was because of my keyboard was pressed, so I switched off my Bluetooth mouse and keyboard. But the computer waked up and went into login page while I did not touch a thing.

I checked system preference --> battery --> schedule, the start up remains unchecked. Then I had to look for the log with `pmset -g log|grep -e " Sleep  " -e " Wake  "` and showed this:
[image]
Could anyone help me find the reason behind this issue?

Comment: Seems to be a USB device which triggers the wake-up.

Comment: Hope you figure it out. Better if you include any diagnostics as text whenever possible instead of a picture.

Comment: Can you update to macOS 12.3.1 and try again?